# removing duplicate log records

Tags: sql-server

SO I have a query that searches my items table and returns all records with a prodstat <> NULL and it does some summed inventory fields.

I have tied this query to another table which is an audit log table and it returns the new prodstat, old prodstat, who changed it, and what date.

The problem is it is bringing in extra records if there have been multiple changes to the field.  I am trying to use max on the createdate of the log record to pull only the newest record.  Problem is when I add it to my other query, I only get the records which have been changed in the log file.

What I am looking for is all the item records with prodstat <> Null and the fields createdate,newvalue,oldvalue updated from the log table.

The data output should look like this

```
prodstat  item.num  item.desc  onhandinv  newprodstat   oldprodstat  changeddate
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    Select 
      item.Uf_ProdStat,
      item.item,
      item.description,
      a.UpdatedBy,
      (Select SUM(itemloc.qty_on_hand) 
         from itemloc 
           where itemloc.item = item.item and itemloc.loc = 'Main')as qty_onhand,
      a.createDate,
      a.OldValue,
      a.NewValue    
    From item
      left join AuditLog a on item.item = a.KeyValue and MessageType = 10010
      inner join (select max(createdate)as maxdate, keyvalue
                from AuditLog
            where MessageType = 10010 and NewValue in 
            ('EOL','DISC','WHL','NNO')  
            group by KeyValue)
            tm on A.KeyValue = tm.KeyValue and A.CreateDate = tm.maxdate    
    Where   Uf_ProdStat is Not Null
```

This is returning only the 3 records, that match the changed records in the log file.  I should have 100, the log file part is just being add now.

Comment: Some sample data and table schemas works go a long way in helping you solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I kept working on the inner joins and this one seems to give me everything I need...

```
    From item
          --left join AuditLog a on item.item = a.KeyValue and MessageType = 10010
          left join (select a.messagetype,a.UserName as updatedby,a.CreateDate as recorddate,a.OldValue,a.keyvalue, a.NewValue
                    from AuditLog A
                        right join ( select max(createdate)as maxdate, keyvalue
                                        from AuditLog
                                        where MessageType = 10010 and NewValue in('EOL','NNO','DISC','WSL')
                                        group by KeyValue)
                    tm on A.KeyValue = tm.KeyValue and A.CreateDate = tm.maxdate) AL on AL.keyvalue = item.item
```